# Single ajax for image data and other serialized data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send data2 variable to my PHP script using but with below given code i am getting empty array of $_POST in my controller

```
 var data2 = {
    donation: $("#donationform").serialize(),
    allocation: $("#allocationform").serialize(),
    allocationerrors: { msg: validation() },
    datatoform: new FormData(this)
};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: data2,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data, status) {},
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you cannot send binary `FormData` in an object. You need to do it the other way around; ie. append the data to the `FormData` object and send that in the request. Try this:

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
formData.append('donation', $("#donationform").serialize());
formData.append('allocation', $("#allocationform").serialize());
formData.append('allocationerrors', JSON.stringify({ msg: validation() }));

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function (data, status) {
  },
  error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
  }
});
```

Comment: you are great man dont you know how much u helped me thanks alot

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)